# Oriented 3-manifold fibering over two different surfaces?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

In a [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381914/can-a-3-manifold-fiber-over-two-different-surfaces) post I asked if a closed connected 3-manifold could have fibrations over surfaces $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ with $\Sigma_1 \ncong \Sigma_2$.  I got the great example of $K \times S^1$ where $K$ is the Klein bottle to show that this can indeed occur, however this manifold is not orientable.  Are there any orientable examples of this phenomenon?

Comment: Nope, no orientable examples.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks - is there a somewhat straightforward way to see this?

Comment: It is not hard, but takes some time. How familiar are you with the basics of Seifert manifolds? Circle bundles over surfaces are special cases of these. With few well-understood exceptions, Seifert fibration is unique up to isotopy. All the exceptions occur when the base (as an orbifold - an ordinary surface in you case) has non-negative Euler characteristic. Then the proof boils down to examining the examples one-by-one. (The example I gave for the other question came from thinking about the known exceptional cases.) Nothing better than this, I am afraid.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Oh OK thank you very much.  I figured if I read a bit about Seifert manifolds I could figure this out but I hoped that in this case where we have honest fibrations some group theory might do the trick somehow.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I agree with the general spirit of your answer but I think you made a mistake when checking cases. The lens space $ L_{4,1} $ with four element cyclic fundamental group $ C_4 $ is a circle bundle over $S_2$ but also a circle bundle over $\mathbb{R}P^2 $. Indeed $L_{4,1} $ is isometric to the the unit tangent bundle of the projective plane $ UT(\mathbb{R}P^2) $. See https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/konno.pdf

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Right, I overlooked this example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The only example of a closed connected orientable 3 manifold that fibers over two different surfaces is the lens space $ L_{4,1} $ which is a circle bundle over both $ S^2 $ and $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $.

$ L_{4,1} $ is a circle bundle over the sphere $ S^2 $, the $ n=4 $ case of of the family of bundles
$$
S^1 \to L_{n,1} \to S^2
$$
But $ L_{4,1} $  is also a circle bundle over $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $
$$
S^1 \to L_{4,1} \to \mathbb{R}P^2
$$
Indeed $ L_{4,1} $ is isometric to the unit tangent bundle of the projective plane $ UT(\mathbb{R}P^2 ) $. See

[https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/konno.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/konno.pdf)

This is related to the fact that $ S^2 $ isometrically double covers $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $ while $ UT(S^2) \cong \mathbb{R}P^3 \cong L_{2,1} $ double covers $ L_{4,1} $.